# Ruby sort by multiple values?

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes:

```
a=[{ 'foo'=>0,'bar'=>1 },
   { 'foo'=>0,'bar'=>2 },
   ... ]
```

I want to sort the array first by each hash's 'foo', then by 'bar'. Google tells me this is how it's done:

```
a.sort_by {|h| [ h['foo'],h['bar'] ]}
```

But this gives me the ArgumentError "comparison of Array with Array failed". What does this mean?

Comment: Works for me. Are you using an old version of ruby?

Comment: What you have posted works in 1.8.7.

Comment: Is it possible that the data you think you have and the data you actually have are not the same?

Comment: This exception occurs when the result array used for the comparison contains both nil and non-nil values.

Comment: Also note that Ruby can not compare boolean values, which might also cause this error.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
a.sort { |a, b| [a['foo'], a['bar']] <=> [b['foo'], b['bar']] }
```

Comment: This is the same thing. `Enumerable#sort_by(&block)` is roughly `sort { |a,b| block.call(a) <=> block.call(b) }`, except done in a more efficient way. If this works but `sort_by` does not, then something else is amiss.

Comment: For simple keys sort is more efficient. For complex keys, sort_by is more efficient.

Comment: Hmm, now I'm getting the "You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!" error. The exact array I used is `a=[{'foo'=>0,'bar'=>2},{'foo'=>0,'bar'=>1},{'foo'=>2,'bar'=>1},{'foo'=>1,'bar'=>0}]`.

Comment: Works for me.>> a=[{'foo'=>0,'bar'=>2},{'foo'=>0,'bar'=>1},{'foo'=>2,'bar'=>1},{'foo'=>1,'bar'=>0}]
=> [{"foo"=>0, "bar"=>2}, {"foo"=>0, "bar"=>1}, {"foo"=>2, "bar"=>1}, {"foo"=>1, "bar"=>0}]
>> a.sort { |a, b| [a['foo'], a['bar']] <=> [b['foo'], b['bar']] }
=> [{"foo"=>0, "bar"=>1}, {"foo"=>0, "bar"=>2}, {"foo"=>1, "bar"=>0}, {"foo"=>2, "bar"=>1}]

Comment: Yeah disregard what I just said, I hadn't noticed that you changed sort_by to sort. Oddly though, `a.sort {|a,b| [ a['foo'],a['bar'] ] <=> [b['foo'],b['bar'] ]}` just returns `["foo"]`

Comment: One advantage of sort_by is that it's more DRY.

Comment: Ahaha disregard that too, dumb mistake on my part. I guess using sort_by by mistake has messed with the array somehow? I had to redeclare it. Anyway, it works.

Comment: To sort foo ascending, bar descending: `sort { |a, b| [a['foo'], b['bar']] <=> [b['foo'], a['bar']] }`

Comment: Can anyone help me understand, how `<=>` (spaceship) operator compares array values?

eg:  `[1, 2] <=> [1, 3]`

I understand how `1 <=> 2` is compared.

Answer (score 31):

It probably means you're missing one of the fields 'foo' or 'bar' in one of your objects.

The comparison is coming down to something like `nil <=> 2`, which returns `nil` (instead of `-1`, `0` or `1`) and `#sort_by` doesn't know how to handle `nil`.

Try this:

```
a.sort_by {|h| [ h['foo'].to_i, h['bar'].to_i ]}
```

Answer (score 16):

What you have posted works in Ruby 1.8.7:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > a = [{'foo'=>99,'bar'=>1},{'foo'=>0,'bar'=>2}]
 => [{"foo"=>99, "bar"=>1}, {"foo"=>0, "bar"=>2}] 

ruby-1.8.7-p302 > a.sort_by{ |h| [h['foo'],h['bar']] }
 => [{"foo"=>0, "bar"=>2}, {"foo"=>99, "bar"=>1}] 

ruby-1.8.7-p302 > a.sort_by{ |h| [h['bar'],h['foo']] }
 => [{"foo"=>99, "bar"=>1}, {"foo"=>0, "bar"=>2}]
```

Answer (score 4):

This exception occurs when the result array used for the comparison contains both nil and non-nil values.

Answer (score 1):

This error appeares when you have unstable keys and trying to sort by them.
Example:

```
[{'foo'=>99,'bar'=>1},{'foo'=>0,'bar'=>2, 'qwe' => 7}]
a.sort_by{|v| v['qwe']}
ArgumentError: comparison of NilClass with 7 failed
```

Try to do

```
a.sort_by{|v| [v['qwe']].select{|k| not k.nil?}}
```

But it doesnt work for me in

```
[v['index'],v['count'],v['digit'],v['value']]
```

where digit is unstable

Answer (score 1):

> comparison of Array with Array failed

This means (at least in my case) that the types of array elements are different. When I made sure all array items are of the same time (`Integer`, for example), sorting started to work.

Answer (score 1):

consider compacting the array (removing nil entries), and as a bonus, if it's string comparision, downcase the values for case insensitive sorting.

```
a.compact.sort_by { |h| [h['foo'].downcase, h['bar'].downcase] }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a task where I needed to sort array of hashes by different keys and different directions (by first key `ascending`, by second `descending` and etc.)

I've created this helper class, called it `AwesomeSort` because it's awesome and it's written in Ruby.

https://gist.github.com/pucinsk/36ffef881622b2d9dcca6716f403dc27

Comment: Great code. I suggest to add handling for case where a value is nil