# Sorting: Sort array based on multiple conditions in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have a mulitdimensional array like so:

```
[
  [name, age, date, gender]
  [name, age, date, gender]
  [..]
]
```

I'm wondering the best way to sort this array based on multiple conditions...For instance, how would I sort based on **age** *first* then by name?

I was messing around with the `sort` method like so:

```
array.sort { |a,b| [ a[1], a[0] ] <=> [ b[1], b[0] ] }
```

Besides that I don't really understand this syntax, I'm not getting the results I would expect.  Should I be using the `sort` method?  Should I be individually comparing results by `mapping` the array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort a collection of objects by number (highest first) then by letter (alphabetical)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232470/sort-a-collection-of-objects-by-number-highest-first-then-by-letter-alphabeti)

Comment: @pruett: no disrespect for robbrit's answer, but you should consider the selected answer, there is nothing wrong with using Enumerable#sort *except* when Enumerable#sort_by does the job. This can be misleading for people landing here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby sort by multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309723/ruby-sort-by-multiple-values)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You should *always* use `sort_by` for a keyed sort. Not only is it much more readable, it is also *much* more efficient. In addition, I would also prefer to use destructuring bind, again, for readability:

```
array.sort_by {|name, age| [age, name] }
```

Answer (score 16):

This should do the trick:

```
array.sort { |a,b| [ a[1], a[0] ] <=> [ b[1], b[0] ] }
```

So what does this do? It uses a lot of Ruby idioms.

- First is blocks, which are sort of like callbacks or anonymous functions/classes in other languages. The `sort` method of Array uses them to compare two elements based on the return value of the block. You can read all about them [here](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_containers.html).
- Next is the `<=>` operator. It returns -1 if the first argument is less than the second, 0 if they are equal, and 1 if the first is greater than the second. When you use it with arrays, it will compare the arrays element-wise until one of them returns -1 or 1. If the arrays are equal, you will get 0.

Comment: You could also use `sort_by { |a| [a[1], a[0]] }`, constructing all those arrays doesn't come for free.

Answer (score 7):

As I understand it you want to order by age first, and then if more than one record has the same age, arrange that subset by name.

---

This works for me

```
people = [
      ["bob", 15, "male"], 
      ["alice", 25, "female"], 
      ["bob", 56, "male"], 
      ["dave", 45, "male"], 
      ["alice", 56, "female"], 
      ["adam", 15, "male"]
    ]

people.sort{|a,b| (a[1] <=> b[1]) == 0 ? (a[0] <=> b[0]) : (a[1] <=> b[1]) }

# The sorted array is

[["adam", 15, "male"], 
 ["bob", 15, "male"], 
 ["alice", 25, "female"], 
 ["dave", 45, "male"], 
 ["alice", 56, "female"], 
 ["bob", 56, "male"]]
```

---

What this is doing is comparing by age first, and if the age is the same (<=> returs 0) it comparing the name.

Comment: very nice!  i like that syntax

Comment: what if the age is same and then we want to sort the name in descending order?

Comment: @Inquisitive then in that case I think you would switch the "a" and the "b" in the "(a[1] <=> b[1])" on the right.