# Sort Ruby array by a set of parameters, fall back to next parameter in case it's undefined

Tags: ruby, sorting

In Ruby, what would be the best way to sort an array of objects by an `order` property that may or may not exist, and if it doesn't, then fall back to sorting based on a property named `title`?

Comment: Jeff, I found your question interesting, but in need of clarification.  A simple example, including the desired result, would be a big help. If you do an edit to clarify, there is a possibility the hold will be retracted.

Comment: probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888030/sorting-sort-array-based-on-multiple-conditions-in-ruby?rq=1

Comment: Yes, it does seem like a pretty similar question. I actually asked it again because the other solutions I tried didn't work, but it turned out that was because of the data structure, not the solutions. Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are after, but a quick solution could be:

```
arr = [{a:"never", b:"anna"}, {a:"always", b:"bob"}, {b:"colin"}, {b:"abe"}]
arr.sort_by! {|o| o[:a] ? o[:a] : o[:b] }
#=> [{:b=>"abe"}, {:a=>"always", :b=>"bob"}, {:b=>"colin"}, {:a=>"never", :b=>"anna"}]
```

Comment: or `{ |o| o[a] || o[b] }`.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that you will sometimes be comparing one record's `:a` with another record's `:b`. @Sacha - In your case, you would have an integer (order) being compared with a string (title), so I think you would see this error: `ArgumentError: comparison of String with 1 failed`

Comment: @nathan.f77 yes, this is what I understood from the question. That, indeed, when :a is not present sort by :b. So you would be sorting object1's :a with object2's :b, say. Of course, I also assumed that both :a and :b are of the same type.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to perform a sort with a fallback in Ruby:

```
Item = Struct.new(:order, :title)

items = [
  Item.new(nil, "d"),
  Item.new(nil, "b"),
  Item.new(1,   "a"),
  Item.new(3,   "c"),
  Item.new(2,   "e")
]

sorted_items = items.sort do |a, b|
  if a.order && b.order
    a.order <=> b.order
  elsif a.order || b.order
    # This prioritizes all items with an order
    a.order ? -1 : 1
  else
    a.title.to_s <=> b.title.to_s
  end
end

require 'awesome_print'
ap sorted_items

# [
#     [0] {
#         :order => 1,
#         :title => "a"
#     },
#     [1] {
#         :order => 2,
#         :title => "e"
#     },
#     [2] {
#         :order => 3,
#         :title => "c"
#     },
#     [3] {
#         :order => nil,
#         :title => "b"
#     },
#     [4] {
#         :order => nil,
#         :title => "d"
#     }
# ]
```

Let me also say that if you are fetching records from a database, then it would be better to do the sorting in your SQL query. If `Item` was an ActiveRecord model, you could do something like:

```
Item.order('order ASC NULLS LAST, title ASC')
```

([NULLS LAST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12767777/304706) can be used in Postgres, [check out this answer for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8174026/304706).)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right here is how to do this:

```
arr1 = [{order: 1, title: 2},{title: 4},{order: 2, title: 1}]
arr2 = [{order: 1, title: 2},{order: 7, title: 4},{order: 2, title: 1}]

def sort_it prop1, prop2, ar
  ar.map{|el| el[prop1]}.include?(nil) ?
     ar.sort_by{|el| el[prop2]}
    :
     ar.sort_by{|el| el[prop1]}
end

p sort_it(:order, :title, arr1)
p sort_it(:order, :title, arr2)
```

Which gives:

```
#=> [{:order=>2, :title=>1}, {:order=>1, :title=>2}, {:title=>4}]
#=> [{:order=>1, :title=>2}, {:order=>2, :title=>1}, {:order=>7, :title=>4}]
```

So, the algorythm is simple: select all objects' properties (`:order` in our case) and if output temporary array contains at least one `nil` then sort by second given property, otherwise -- by first.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
def sort_array(array)
  sort_by_property_name = sort_by_property_present?(array, :order, :title)
  array.sort_by { |ob| ob.public_send(sort_by_property_name) }
end

def sort_by_property_present?(array, primary_name, fallback_name)
  array.all? { |ob| ob.respond_to?(name) } || return fallback_name
  primary_name
end
```

Comment: I'm not good still in proper method naming as per their roles.. Please suggest a good name. I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to sort based on field/parameter that may or may not be present, I am assuming:

1. When the parameter is present sort by it.
2. When unavailable fall back to the next parameter.

Please review the following code that can sort an object array based on a number of fields, the system keeps falling back to the next field if the field is unavailable. Its developed with the assumption that the last field will definitely be present.

```
class CondtionalSort
  def run(array: a, keys_to_order_by: keys)
    array.sort do |e1, e2|
      keys_to_order_by.each do |key|
        break e1[key] <=> e2[key] if (e1.key?(key) && e2.key?(key))
      end
    end
  end
end


ArrayTest = [{order: 1, title: 2},{title: 4},{order: 2, title: 1}]
ArrayTest_SORTED = [{:order=>1, :title=>2}, {:order=>2, :title=>1}, {:title=>4}]

sorter = CondtionalSort.new
sorter.run array: ArrayTest, keys_to_order_by: [:order, :title]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just use an array as the sort_by:

```
# sample data:
Item = Struct.new(:property1, :property2, :property3)
collection = [Item.new("thing1", 3, 6), Item.new("thing1", 3, 1), Item.new("aaa", 1,1) ]

# sort
collection.sort_by{|item| [item.property1, item.property2, item.property3] }
# => [#<struct Item property1="aaa", property2=1, property3=1>, 
      #<struct Item property1="thing1", property2=3, property3=1>, 
      #<struct Item property1="thing1", property2=3, property3=6>]
```

Comment: I wonder if that actually works...

Comment: I don't think this works. I get `ArgumentError: comparison of Array with Array failed` when I try this, both in Ruby IRb, and in the Rails console.

Comment: You have to actually line up your test conditions so it has comparable properties in the array, but I use it all the time.   I'll add some sample test code.