# Complex subsorts on an array of arrays

Tags: ruby, sorting

I wrote a quick method that confirms that data coming from a webpage is sorted correctly:

```
def subsort_columns(*columns)
  columns.transpose.sort
end
```

Which worked for basic tests. Now, complex subsorts have been introduced, and I'm pretty certain I'll need to still use an array, since hashes can't be guaranteed to return in a specific order. The order of the input in this case represents subsort priority.

```
# `columns_sort_preferences` is an Array in the form of:
# [[sort_ascending_bool, column_data]]
# i.e.
# subsort_columns([true, column_name], [false, column_urgency], [true, column_date])
# Will sort on name ascending, then urgency descending, and finally date ascending.
def subsort_columns(*columns_sort_preferences)

end
```

This is where I'm stuck. I want to do this cleanly, but can't come up with anything but rolling out a loop for each subsort that occurs on any parent sort...but it sounds wrong.

Feel free to offer better suggestions, as I'm not tied to this implementation.

Here's some test data:

```
a =   [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3]
b = %w(a b c c b b a b c)
c = %w(x z z y x z z y z)
subsort_columns([true, a], [false, b], [false, c])
=> [[1, 'c', 'z'], 
    [1, 'b', 'z'], 
    [1, 'a', 'x'], 
    [2, 'c', 'y'], 
    [2, 'b', 'x'], 
    [3, 'c', 'z'],
    [3, 'b', 'z'],
    [3, 'b', 'y'],
    [3, 'a', 'z']]
```

### Update:

Marking for reopen because I've linked to this question in a comment above the function in our codebase that *I provided [as my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18003888/881224)*. Not to mention the help I got from [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17999714/881224) that clearly displays the solution to my problem, whom I'd like to give a bounty to for giving me a tip in the right direction. Please don't delete this question, it is very helpful to me. If you disagree, at least leave a comment specifying what is unclear to you.

Comment: [possible answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309723/ruby-sort-by-multiple-values#comment4679922_4309737)

Comment: In Ruby 1.9+ hashes will preserve insertion order. This is made clear in the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html): "Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted." In any case you need to give a better example of both sample input and desired output formats.

Comment: @tadman I can't use a Hash anyway. The keys for the column data might not be unique without adding some key to it, which isn't good.

Comment: If you have duplicate keys, yes, you'd need to use the Array method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Sort on each entry in `ticket_columns`, starting with the first column, then second, etc.
# Complex sorts are supported. If the first element in each `ticket_columns` is a true/false
# boolean (specifying if an ascending sort should be used), then it is sorted that way. 
# If omitted, it will sort all ascending.
def _subsort_columns(*ticket_columns)
  # Is the first element of every `ticket_column` a boolean?
  complex_sort = ticket_columns.all? { |e| [TrueClass, FalseClass].include? e[0].class }
  if complex_sort
    data = ticket_columns.transpose
    sort_directions = data.first
    column_data = data[1..-1].flatten 1
    sorted = column_data.transpose.sort do |cmp_first, cmp_last|
      cmp_which = sort_directions.map { |b| b ? cmp_first : cmp_last }
      cmp_these = sort_directions.map { |b| b ? cmp_last : cmp_first }
      cmp_left, cmp_right = [], []
      cmp_which.each_with_index { |e, i| cmp_left << e[i] }
      cmp_these.each_with_index { |e, i| cmp_right << e[i] }
      cmp_left <=> cmp_right
    end
    sorted
  else
    ticket_columns.transpose.sort
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [sort {|a, b| block} → new_ary](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-sort):

```
a =   [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3]
b = %w(a b c c b b a b c)
c = %w(x z z y x z z y z)
sorted = [a, b, c].transpose.sort do |el1, el2|
  [el1[0], el2[1], el2[2]] <=> [el2[0], el1[1], el1[2]] 
end
```

Result:

```
[[1, "c", "z"],
 [1, "b", "z"],
 [1, "a", "x"]
 [2, "c", "y"],
 [2, "b", "x"],
 [3, "c", "z"],
 [3, "b", "z"],
 [3, "b", "y"],
 [3, "a", "z"]]
```

For a *descending column* reverse the left and right elements of the spaceship operator.

Comment: I'm generalizing this into a function. Thanks.

Comment: [Check out my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18003888/881224). Thanks for your help, I'll hook you up with some bounty in a couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to do a series of '[stable sorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability)' in reverse order.  Start with the inner sort and work out to the outer.  The stability property means that the inner sort order remains intact.

Unfortunately, Ruby's `sort` is not stable.  But see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15442298/10396) for a workaround.